# Logical conjunction for multiple arraylists

Tags: java, arraylist

There are multiple arraylists (the number of arraylists is apriori unknown). In each arraylist I need to find an element that provides logical conjunction with elements from other lists. Note that the comparison is made only for non-null values.

```
ArrayList<Integer[]> list1 = new ArrayList<Integer[]>();
ArrayList<Integer[]> list2 = new ArrayList<Integer[]>();
ArrayList<Integer[]> list3 = new ArrayList<Integer[]>();

list1.add(new Integer[]{1,2,3,4});
list1.add(new Integer[]{1,4,5,6});

list2.add(new Integer[]{1,4,null,null});

list3.add(new Integer[]{null,null,null,5});
list3.add(new Integer[]{null,null,null,6});
```

In this case the answer should be:

```
list1: {1,4,5,6}
list2: {1,4,null,null}
list3: {null,null,null,6}
```

Since the number of arraylists is apriori unknown, I thought to use recursion. However, perhaps there might be simpler solutions?

Comment: How does your recursive solution work?  Just because there is an unknown at compile time doesn't in itself make it a good candidate for recursion.

Comment: @Jonathan: It makes sense,because as I said the comparison is made only for non-null positions. So, 4th position in the list3 is not compared to the 4th position in list2.

Comment: I'm not clear what you mean by logical injunction here.  Do you mean it in the sense of a set intersection?  In sets position isn't important, the only thing that matters is membership.  Can you define it how you want it to be used?

Comment: @Mark Peters: Yes, sets intersection, where positions are important. But if a certain position has a value "null", than it's just ignored.

Comment: @Mark Peters: I don't have a code of recursion. I'm just thinking about the best solution. Therefore, I'm asking here for other ideas. Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you might want to use Google's excellent [guava-libraries](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/).  Check out the [Sets class](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v11.0/javadoc/index.html).

Comment: Do you mean "Map<K,V> entriesInCommon()"? Could you please give some example or web-link with examples?