# Google Guava library

Tags: java, guava

This question is related to the [previously asked one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8748931/logical-conjunction-for-multiple-arraylists). As it was suggested I'm trying to use Google Guava library to find sets intersection.

```
HashMap m1 = new HashMap();
m1.put(1, new Integer[]{1,2,3,4});
m1.put(2, new Integer[]{1,4,5,6});

HashMap m2 = new HashMap();
m2.put(1, new Integer[]{1,5,null,null});
m2.put(2, new Integer[]{1,4,null,null});
```

Now, as far as I understand, I should apply the Guava function [entriesInCommon()](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/MapDifference.html#entriesInCommon()) to find the entries that appear in both maps. But I don't understand how can I do this. Any ideas? Thanks.

UPDATE: keys in the maps

Comment: Why are you putting two entries with the same key into each map? The second entry will just overwrite the first.

Comment: @ALL: sorry, it was my syntax mistake. Updated now.

Comment: Erm, why not `new Set<Integer>(m1.keys()).retainAll(m2.keys())`? No need for Guava... This new set will contain common keys.

Comment: Okay, I looked again at your previous question and really don't understand what you're going for. Why are you using `Integer[]`s instead of, say, `Set<Integer>`s?

Comment: @MДΓΓ БДLL: Because I cannot compile "Set<Integer> s1 = new HashSet<Integer>(); s1.add(new Integer[]{1,2,3,4});"

Comment: @fge: This solutions does not solve the problem described in the post, because it does not account for "null". I.e. {1,2,3} and {1,2,null} will be evaluated as different ones, although I need them to be the same.

Comment: @MДΓΓ БДLL: It was very difficult to follow your comments, because you always deleted them, while I was answering.

Comment: What you would want the output to be for the example above?

Answer (score 5):

Adding arrays of integers is not going to work in Java's type system.

When you say

```
Set<Integer> s1 = new HashSet<Integer>();
s1.add(new Integer[]{1,2,3,4});
```

what you should be writing is either

```
Set<Integer> s1 = new HashSet<Integer>();
s1.add(1);
s1.add(2);
s1.add(3);
s1.add(4);
```

or possibly

```
Set<Integer> s1 = new HashSet<Integer>();
s1.addAll(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4));
```

Once you've constructed these, you can take the intersection using retainAll() and the like.